# Как заполнить блоком всю свободную площадь страницы?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Верстал, верстал и уперся в вопрос: простенькая страничка, разделенная на 2 части по вертикали - сверху блок, под ним таблица. 
http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/73302_0000000000.png
В таблице определенное количество ячеек, в которых содержатся кнопочки. Есть желание сделать такую штуку: высота верхнего блока фиксирована, а таблица заполняет всю оставшуюся часть страницы, причем размер ячеек и соответственно кнопок меняется в зависимости от размера этой самой части страницы. Опытные верстальщики, подскажите новичку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тянуть контент на высоту всего экрана - не очень верное решение. Экраны у всех разные.
Точно задача выполняется с привлечением js - кода.
[смотреть >>](http://sinsite.ru/temp.html)
<br>
**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
<div id="block_top" class="block">Блок сверху</div>
<table id="table_content" class="block">
    <tr>
        <td>Столбец 1</td>
        <td>Столбец 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

</div>

**CSS**

```
html, body{ height: 100%;}
#wrapper{height: 100%;width: 100%;}
#table_content{height: 100%;}
#block_top{height: 150px;}
.block{border: 1px solid #fff;margin:10px;text-align: center;width: 1000px;}
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            var h=$(this).height();
            var h2=$("#block_top").height();
            $("html").height(h-h2-50);
            $("#table_content").height(h-h2-250);
        });
    </script>
```

> Если js - отключить то появится полоса прокрутки.

Comment: благодарю за ответ.
>Тянуть контент на высоту всего экрана - не очень верное решение. Экраны у всех разные.  

Вы абсолютно правы, просто это задача для верстки мобильного приложения - калькулятора, а в таких условиях, насколько я понимаю, жизненно важно, чтобы максимальная площадь экрана была покрыта да и элементы оставались кликабельными. Правильно ли я понял, что силами CSS такое сделать никак нельзя?

Comment: Есть. 
Для вашей задачи подойдет решение bootstrap 
Практический пример: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/
Теория: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic
Там много чего еще полезного и стильного.